# QGIS, drawing entity with a magnetized knot

Tags: qgis, map-drawing

I wanted to know if it was possible to draw with a magnetized knot, like Archi or Autocad ... !?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "magnetized knot", do you mean a digitizing puck on a tablet, like this: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyGgCIGoNAF4GwLQD5Xsdj9U7e3Yvn8_g09Aieq42Z-40_d7vC ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE .. It would help if you explained what you meant my "Magnetized Knot" I have never heard of it and neither has Google .. You can do that by editing your question ..

Comment: I'm guessing you may mean 'snapping'? If so, check the Snapping Options in QGIS, or do a search using that as a keyword.